# iOS 5.1: Handling close modal dialog

Tags: ios, ios5.1

I have a `UIViewController` A which opens up a modal popup dialog B via `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

When the modal windows B closes (or a button on it is pushed), I'd like to call a function back on the first view controller A.

Which customization point can I use to handle the closing of the modal window B?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've found that the easiest way to do something like this is to create a global BOOL, possibly in the app delegate which you can set to yes when you navigate to B, then back in A's viewDidAppear check if the BOOL is YES, perform the action, and set the BOOL back to NO.

Comment: Unfortunately the viewDidAppear is not triggered again after the modal dialog closes...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I often use NSNotifications for this kind of thing.

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/